# How to get information about SDK's installed in an iOS App from its ipa file

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, ipa

I want to write a PHP Script to get information about SDK's installed in an iOS App from its IPA file. I have prepared a [PHP script](http://jarviisinfotech.org/reverseengineeriosapp/CFPropertyList-master/examples/findInfoFromIpa.php) for getting Bundle ID of the app from its IPA. I am following these steps in order to get that Bundle ID:
1. upload IPA file
2. rename the file from .ipa to .zip
3. extract the zip file
4. then parse the Info.plist file under Payload/appname.app/ folder and get the PHP array as a result.
5. then read the key "CFBundleIdentifier" from that array to get Bundle identifier.

But now my requirement is to get the information of SDKs installed in the app from its IPA.
I want results something like this:
https://s31.postimg.org/n7ftboft7/sdk_s.png

Please help. Its very important for me. thanks in advance. Any kind of help will be appreciated.